# Equivalence of Links

Tags: knot-theory

Let $L,J$ be two equivalent links. Let $L_1,...,L_n$ be the components of $L$ and $J_1,
...,J_m$ the components of $J$. Is it necessarily true that $n = m$ and each $L_i$ is equivalent to a distinct $J_k$ as knots?

I believe $n = m$ because I cannot see how Reidemeister moves can change the number of components, but I'm not completely convinced with the second statement. Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Label each of the $n$ components of $L$ with distinct numbers $1,\dots,n$.  Apply Reidemeister moves that show $L$ is equivalent to $J$, keeping track of the labels -- analyzing each of the three Reidemeister moves separately, it's clear that the labels can be preserved through each move.  In particular, components with different labels never merge and components never split into two components.

At the end, the labels can be used to label the components of $J$.  By the analysis, each component gets a distinct label, and since this is an equivalence of links all components get a label.  Since the $n$ labels can label both $L$ and $J$, they each have $n$ components.  Furthermore, the labels form a bijection from the components of $L$ to the components of $J$ with the property that each component is mapped to an equivalent component, since we can erase individual components from entire sequences of Reidemeister moves to get new sequences of Reidemeister moves.

*Warning:* The converse isn't true: just because two links have a bijection between their components such that each component maps to an equivalent knot, it doesn't mean the links are equivalent.  There are infinitely many inequivalent two-component links whose components are unknots.

Comment: Wonderful answer, thank you! This the sort of argument I was thinking about, but I wasn't sure if Reidemeister moves involving arcs from different components would still preserve equivalence of the individual components.

Comment: @JLinsta Just to say it again, maybe more clearly: if we have a sequence of Reidemeister moves, then, choosing a component of the link, we can delete it from each step while forgetting each Reidemeister move that had to do with that particular component.  If you delete all but one component, then you're left with a sequence of Reidemeister moves carrying that component of the diagram for $L$ to an equivalent component of the diagram for $J$.

Comment: Ok let's say we delete all of the components of $L$ other than $L_0$. Is it possible that all of the Reidemeister moves involving $L_0$ also involve another component of $L$? If this were the case, $L_0$ would remain unchanged after deletion. Does this mean $J$ necessarily also has $L_0$ as one of its components?

Comment: @JLinsta Yeah, it's possible for there to be no "$L_0$-specific" Reidemeister moves.  Let's say a *subdiagram* is a diagram from deleting components.  In this case, both $L$ and $J$ have a 1-component subdiagram in common ($L_0$).